# First of two blocks of code of reading from a file not executing in python

Tags: python, file, assembly, io

As part of an assignment I'm writing an assembler in python that takes simplified assembly language and outputs binary machine language. Part of my code is below, where I'm reading from the assembly code in two passes. The first pass (the first line of with open(filename, "r") as asm_file) in the first block of reading from the file asm_file doesn't seem to be executing. The second one is executing fine, well it's not outputting the correct binary because the first block doesn't seem to be running correctly or at all. Am I using the "with open(filename. "r") as file:" correctly? What am I missing? Thanks in advance.

For completeness an input file is given below the code:

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
    #fill Symbol Table and C instruction Tables
    symbol_table = symbolTable()
    symbol_table.initialiseTable()

    comp_table = compTable()
    comp_table.fillTable()

    dest_table = destTable()
    dest_table.fillTable()

    jump_table = jumpTable()
    jump_table.fillTable()

    #import the file given in the command line
    filename = sys.argv[-1]
    #open output_file
    output_file = open('output.hack', 'w')
    #open said file and work on contents line by line
    with open(filename, "r") as asm_file:   ##### This one doesn't seem to run because
        #1st pass of input file    ##### The print command below doesn't output anything
        num_instructions = -1
        for line in asm_file:
            #ignoring whitespace and comments
            if line != '\n' and not line.startswith('//'):
                num_instructions += 1
                #remove in-line comments
                if '//' in line:
                    marker, line = '//', line
                    line = line[:line.index(marker)].strip()
                    #search for beginning of pseudocommand
                    if line.startswith('('):
                        num_instructions -= 1
                        label = line.strip('()')
                        address = num_instructions + 1
                        symbol_table.addLabelAddresses(label, address)
                        print(num_instructions)   ###### This print command doesn't output anything

    with open(filename, "r") as asm_file:   
        #2nd pass of input file
        for line in asm_file:
            #ignoring whitespace and comments
            if line != '\n' and not line.startswith('//') and not line.startswith('('):
                #remove in-line comments
                if '//' in line:
                    marker, line = '//', line
                    line = line[:line.index(marker)].strip()
                #send each line to parse function to unpack into its underlying fields  
                instruction = parseLine(line.strip(' \n'))
                inst = Instruction(instruction)
                binary_string = inst.convertToBin()
                #write to output file
                output_file.write(binary_string +'\n')

    output_file.close()
```

An input file example:

```
// This file is part of www.nand2tetris.org

    // and the book "The Elements of Computing Systems"

    // by Nisan and Schocken, MIT Press.

    // File name: projects/06/max/Max.asm



    // Computes R2 = max(R0, R1)  (R0,R1,R2 refer to  RAM[0],RAM[1],RAM[2])



       @R0

       D=M              // D = first number

       @R1

       D=D-M            // D = first number - second number

       @OUTPUT_FIRST

       D;JGT            // if D>0 (first is greater) goto output_first

       @R1

       D=M              // D = second number

       @OUTPUT_D

       0;JMP            // goto output_d

    (OUTPUT_FIRST)

       @R0             

       D=M              // D = first number

    (OUTPUT_D)

       @R2

       M=D              // M[2] = D (greatest number)

    (INFINITE_LOOP)

       @INFINITE_LOOP

       0;JMP            // infinite loop
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the first `with`, starting with

```
#search for beginning of pseudocommand
```

are you quite sure you don't want that and the following lines dedented a level?

As is, the only way to get to your `print` is if a line satisfies both

```
if '//' in line:
```

and

```
if line.startswith('('):
```

There are no lines in your input file satisfying both, so the `print` never executes.

In the second `with`, there are only two indented lines after *its*

```
if '//' in line:
```

Comment: Thanks that's outputting the correct instruction line numbers. Now if I can only get the correct label and address to output to symbolTable and output to correct binary. The address to add to symbol table is the line number of the next instruction after the pseudocommand (the label in the () parentheses, but the pseudocommands are not counted in the instruction line numbers. Currently it doesn't seem to be outputting the correct line number and modifying the code say "address = num_instruction + 1" doesn't change the address in output. I think the problem may be somewhere else.

Answer (score 1):

Your problem seems to be that your code checks if a line starts with a `(`, but in the assembly it has a tab before an instruction so that it doesn't work. You should probably do a `line.strip()` after your first if statement like so

```
with open(filename, "r") as asm_file:
    num_of_instructions = -1
    for line in asm_file
        if line != "\n":
            line.strip()
            #rest of code
```

Incidentally, is the print statement supposed to execute every time it finds a line? Because if it doesn't, you should put it after the for loop. That is why it is not outputting anything

Edit: As @TimPeters says, the print statement will also only execute if it starts with an open bracket and has a comment in it